# Laravel4 Authority defining abilities

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, authority

I have problem with defining abilities in Laravel4 and Authority ( https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4 ).
That rule in authority config should work:

```
$authority->allow('manage', 'Post', function($self, $post){
  // return ($post->sth ... )
});
```

But the problem is with $post, which is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it this way:

```
$authority->allow('manage', 'Post', function($self) use ($post) {
  // return ($post->sth ... )
});
```

Comment: Well, "Undefined variable" error. That`s not also a passing varaible by reference.